# FileStream.read() not getting time duration for some voice files

Tags: c#-4.0

Below is my code in which i want to get time duration for .DSS voice file. Some of file getting time duration but in some of file it returns zero value so i am getting error of "Input string was not in a correct format".

```
const int durationOffset = 62;
const int durationLength = 6;
const int headerLength = durationOffset + durationLength;
using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(Path.Combine(uploadPath, newFileName)))
{
      var fileHeader = new byte[headerLength + 1];
      fileStream.Read(fileHeader, 0, headerLength);

      var hoursData = new byte[2];
      var minutesData = new byte[2];
      var secondsData = new byte[2];

      Array.Copy(fileHeader, durationOffset, hoursData, 0, 2);
      Array.Copy(fileHeader, durationOffset + 2, minutesData, 0, 2);
      Array.Copy(fileHeader, durationOffset + 4, secondsData, 0, 2);
      TimeSpan fileTimeDuration = new  TimeSpan(int.Parse(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(hoursData)), int.Parse(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(minutesData)), int.Parse(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(secondsData)));

      timeDuration = fileTimeDuration.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put your code under try catch block

```
try
{
   //your code
}
catch(IOException ex)
{
  //Handle io exception
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That already i did but i want time duration for that voice file.

Comment: what exception message it actually throws to you?

Comment: here time duration value not getting for it will pass zero in TimeSpan() and in that it will cast the zero string to integer so it will give me "Input string was not in a correct format"

Comment: before invoking TimeSpan method check for if(zero_string!=null || zero_string==0) like that, with in this if part, call TimeSpan method.